# Adding a non-empty string to a vector using push_back, the vector contents are empty. Why is the string not added to the vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector<string> func(string mag) {
  vector<string> s1;
  string temp1;
  string temp2;

  temp1[0] = 'a';
  temp1[1] = 'b';
  temp1[2] = 'c';

  temp2 += "xyz";

  s1.push_back(temp1);
  s1.push_back(temp2);
  return s1;
}

int main() {
  string st;
  vector<string> xyz;
  xyz = func(st);

  for (int a = 0; a < xyz.size(); a++)
    cout << xyz[a] << ',';
}
```

The output of the above code is `,xyz,` even though I was expecting `abc,xyz,`. The string `temp1`, added to the vector, is not printed.

The string `temp1` is non-empty, and printing it out gives output `abc`, but pushing it to the vector `s1` and printing out the vector, the string `temp1` is not printed, while string `temp2`, where `"xyz"` is added to it as `temp2+="xyz"`, is added to the vector and is printed when the contents of the vector are printed.

Can someone explain to me why the string `temp1` is not appearing in the vector contents?

Comment: Unrelated: don't use  [`#include<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065)

Comment: Please  indent your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string temp1;` creates an empty string. Accessing any of its elements is an out-of-bounds-access causing *undefined behaviour*. If you want to access a string's contents like this, resize it before using it:

```cpp
string temp1;
//    VVVVVV
temp1.resize(3); // now it contains 3 elements

temp1[0]='a'; // set first element, ok
temp1[1]='b'; // set second element, ok
temp1[2]='c'; // set third element, ok
```

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
string temp1;
temp1[0]='a';  // UB
```

invokes undefined behavior. `temp1` has size 0, so indexing at the first position (index 0) is not allowed (as pointed out in the comments, there is an exception that *writing* the character `'\0'` at the `size` index *is* allowed).

Instead, add the characters using `+=` or `push_back` instead. Or resize the string to the appropriate size before indexing into it.

Comment: Thanks! But if I print the string temp1 I get 'abc' as the output. If it's not allowed, why does the string have the correct values?

Comment: UB means anything can happen. Sometimes the values might appear to be right, but the *entire* program is broken.

Comment: Ohh. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @cigien "*temp1 has size 0, so indexing at the first position (index 0) is not allowed*" - technically, in C++11 and later, it *IS* allowed to write to the position at `index=size()`, but the only `char` value allowed to be written to that position is `'\0'` otherwise UB occurs. Writing any `char` value to `index>size()` is always UB.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the correction, I appreciate it. Edited the answer. I never seem to remember that exception :p

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your code here:

```
string temp1;

temp1[0]='a'; // Oops - past the end of the string!
temp1[1]='b'; // Oops - past the end of the string!
temp1[2]='c'; // Oops - past the end of the string!
```

In each of the indicated lines, you're writing past the end of the string, which leads to undefined behavior.

If you want to set `temp1` to be `"abc"`, you could try

```
temp1 = "abc";
```

or

```
temp1 += 'a';
temp2 += 'b';
temp3 += 'c';
```

Comment: Thanks for that ! But if I print string temp1, I get the correct, expected output 'abc' . Why does that happen if it should lead to undefined behaviour?

Comment: @adikj Undefined behavior means the code is broken in such a way that the code could do anything. Just because it outputs what you expect does not mean it is not broken.